# Limit echo of variable in PHP to get the desired characters

Tags: php, parsing, php-parse-error, php-parser

`$response` var has a component called `custom_test_name` which looks like below:

```
[Test_Name]ad.no.check1.check2.check3
```

and here is the small PHP code:

```
<?php
    echo "<class="."com.tests.".$response["custom_test_name"][1]."</class>";
?>
```

This prints the `<class=com.tests.[</class>`..check first character `[` of `custom_test_name` and similarly echoing of `["custom_test_name"][2]` prints `T`, `[3]` prints `e`....However, how to print/echo only the specifics in this case?. For eg. echoing just this `ad.no.check1.check2.check3` and eliminating out that `[Test_Name]`. Is there a way we can specify the range/some other approach?

Comment: It's depend. If you know in advance the text inside `[]`, you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), otherwise you have to use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If custom_test_name is always going to begin with [Test_Name] you can remove it with something like

```
$trimmed = str_replace('[Test_Name]', '', $response->custom_test_name);
echo "<class="."com.tests." . $trimmed . "</class>";
```

If it's not always going to be like that but is going to start with [something], you can use something like

```
$trimmed = preg_replace("/(\[.*\])/", '', $response->custom_test_name);
echo "<class="."com.tests." . $trimmed . "</class>";
```

Comment: Yes, custom_test_name is always going to begin with [Test_Name] and so the first approach works. Thanks @Rodrigo